# jQuery - Add space after and before comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I trying to add space before and after comma in input/text on blur. this code works perfectly but I got a little issue with this, that I want to do this once, if you blur input, it going to add space before and after comma but if you do it again it will add more space.. for example:

**want add space to:**

121212,13335345,345345345,

**Result:**

121212 , 13335345 , 345345345

it's ok but when you blur again, it will add extra space before and after comma again, I do not want this.

```
$('.dss').blur(function () {
    $("#test").val(function (i, v) {
        return v.replace(/,/g, " , ");
    });
});
```

Here is **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ygooapLw/)**

Comment: You could take the easy way out by replacing ` , ` with `,` then replacing them back to ` , `. Although I don't think this is the best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `*` quantifier which will match zero or more times

```js
$('.dss').blur(function() {
  $("#test").val(function(i, v) {
    return v.replace(/\s*,\s*/g, " , ");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="test" type="text" value="09356488891,09356446  " maxlength="50" id="test" />

<input type="" class="dss" />
```